# How to intercept a specific URL with wildcards

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I have an app, two different URLs are fetched. Part of the URL is a hash which needs wildcard pattern, and I want to capture just one URL in an intercept.

But the similarity of the string makes it difficult to get a pattern that works.

```js
/api/v1/payment/duedate?type=payment&cache_buster=...
/api/v1/payment/6309503a5c058a702224?cache_buster=...   // capture this one
```

I tried

```js
cy.intercept('/api/v1/payment/*?cache_buster')
```

It seems I need to negate specific parts of pathname or query params, but it does not seem possible to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed negate a section of the URL, but not in the query parameter parts.

This will select any URL with `/payment/*` but exclude the one with `/payment/duedate`.

```js
cy.intercept('/api/v1/payment/!(duedate*)')
```

You could also try a regex, or use javascript code in a routeHandler callback.